# How to create a Gmail label

Tags: gmail-labels

I am retired.  I can't get a handle on Gmail labels. Google makes the assumption that everyone works in an office. I don't and never have.  And so I am not interested in 'productivity' in the workplace sense. Nothing is a priority these days.

I was quite happy creating various folders for different friends,family members and social activities.

Can you give me some examples of how to set up Gmail labels in the non business sense that can be used for like minded types such as I?

Comment: You can assign more than one label to a message, that is the main difference from folders. See also https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

**The basic idea:**

Take the emails in your inbox and look for ones that are similar in topic. Make a label for them. If there were two or three conversations about Easter2016, then make a label, attach it to those conversations. then archive them.

**now as a step by step approach:**

1. select the conversations you want to group together.
2. click the labels button
3. click new label
4. give it a name
5. Now all the messages will have that label

The cool thing is that each conversation can have multiple labels. So if you want to make so more labels change the conversations you have selected and make another label.

if you no longer need to see the email on the front page, select a conversation and click archive. The archive button just strips off the inbox label. You can see them either by searching for label:easter2016, or by clicking on the name of the label on the left side of the screen.

An archived conversation will appear in the inbox if a new message is received.

If a new conversation is received you can add a label via the label button, or the move to button. The move to just attaches the label and archives the conversation.